# How to tell whether a wave is coherent or not?

Tags: waves, coherence

I know that coherency means constant phase difference,but how to figure it from equation?
Are all sinusoidal waves coherent?

Comment: There is more to chernce that constant phase difference.  Have a look at this article.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_%28physics%29

Comment: I've just ask a partially correlated question here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235709/time-coherency-of-incoherent-light